# Timing out a task using await in .NET 4.5

Tags: vb.net, timeout, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm trying out Async / Await in VB.NET 4.5 and would like my task
to timeout if it doesn't complete within a certain period. I have

```
Await Task.Run( Sub() PerformSomeAction() )
```

which seems neat. I also see there is a form of Task.Run that takes a cancellation token. How could I use this to cancel the task in case of some timeout?

**EDIT**

I have the following prototype solution

```
    Dim cts = New CancellationTokenSource()
    Dim ct As CancellationToken = cts.Token
    Dim delay = Task.Delay(1000)
    Dim completed = Await Task.WhenAny(Task.Run(Sub() PerfomSomeAction(ct), ct), delay)
    If completed Is delay Then
            cts.Cancel()
    End If
```

This looks quite noisy code. Is this good? Another idea would be to handle
the timeout as an exception and use cts.CancelAfter. Something like this??

```
    Dim cts = New CancellationTokenSource()
    Dim ct As CancellationToken = cts.Token
    try
        cts.CancelAfter(1000) 'ms
        Dim completed = Task.Run(Sub() PerformSomeAction(ct), ct)
    catch SomeTimeoutException
    end try
```

and withing PerformSomeAction I throw SomeTimeoutException if I get the
detect the cancelation token.

Comment: You should use the `CancelAfter` approach *in addition to* `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` as svick answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task`s support cooperative cancellation, that means if you want to cancel a `Task` that's already running, the code inside the `Task` has to support cancellation and it decides when will it be canceled. The way to achieve this is to pass the cancellation token to the method and call [`ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested) at suitable places in the code of that method.

If the code in the `Task` doesn't support cancellation, there is no clean way to cancel or abort it.

Comment: And how to neatly detect  in the continuation code that a timeout occurred or the correct behavior occurred. I've given two examples, a timeout exception or checking the Result. Is there a commonly used pattern to keep the flow of code clean?

Comment: Yes, if you properly cancel a `Task`, and then `await` it, it will throw `TaskCancelledException`.